# How to use THIS in child function which is outside of a parent JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `onclick` function

```
$('.modal-trigger').on('click', function() {         
  $('#'+$(this).data('modal')).show();
  calc();  
})

<a class="modal-trigger" data-modal="ft-modal">Link</a>
<div id="ft-modal"></div>
```

I want to add `calc()` function inside

```
function calc() {
  var tt = document.getElementById('#'+this.getAttribute('data-modal')).document.getElementsByClassName("name-line")[0]; 
}
```

The second function is **outside** (above) the *onclick* one, and my problem is that I can't figure it out how to perform a search inside the `<div>` by class name and get the first one that matches the class on plain JS.

And I think that I don't know how to use `this` properly for this particular case.

Comment: Just pass the necessary data as a parameter?

Comment: pass this as parameter

Comment: Unrelated: why do you use the `document.getElementById`, `this.getAttribute`, `document.getElementsByClassName` when you are using jQuery which has such nicer syntax for all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass *this* object to the function so that you can refer that inside the function. You can simplify your code by using jQuery:

```js
$('.modal-trigger').on('click', function() {         
  $('#'+$(this).data('modal')).show();
  calc(this); // pass this here 
})

function calc(el) {
  var tt = $('#'+$(el).data('modal')).find('.name-line')[0];
  console.log(tt); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="modal-trigger" data-modal="ft-modal">Link</a>
<div id="ft-modal">
  <span class="name-line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I have to use var $tt = in this case with "$"? @Mamun

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `this` to the `calc` function with `.call`:

```
calc.call(this);
```

The `calc` function needs no change then.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the comments...

```
$('.modal-trigger').on('click', function() {         
    ...
    calc(this);  
});

function calc(ele) {
    ...
}
```

using `document.getElementById` in a jQuery script is questionable;

better use `$(ele).data('modal')` to obtain the data attribute.

of couse both ways would work, nevertheless the readability would be improved

... that's why it is called "write less, do more".

Comment: or maybe even shorter: `$(ele).data('modal')`?

Comment: Don't know why but I still get - Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName', I think the problem now is in the search for the elements by class @Martin Zeitler

Comment: @AndrewK you are mixing up vanilla JS with jQuery (while `getElementsByClassName` is a method of `document`). see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ... there also is the `>` operator, for selecting child elements... it works, just alike CSS selectors work.

Comment: Ok, but how do I "get" the element what I need and bind it to var?

Comment: @AndrewK since the id is unique, you can get a handle with `$('#ft-modal')` or with `$('#ft-modal > .name-line')[0]` or even `$('.name-line')[0]` while class `name-line` only exists in there and nowhere else. being explicit generally is better, in order to prevent wrongful selects, when the DOM gets rather complex.